# Is there any way to extract all css classes used in external css file to use in AMP

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, amp-html

I have a website like static webpage and its made using tailwincss cdn
and now i want to convert this page in AMP-HTML page

So i want to use the styles of tailwind but not using the external css, as its not supported in AMP

One idea came to my mind is if we can extract all used css from cdn library and use it separately inside the ... tag it could work

If you have done with this thing before or u know how to handle this please help

Thank-you in advance all of you

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to extract 'only' the css rules that are being applied to a specific page, from a much larger set of CSS rules. Then you might consider using some kind of critical css generator:

https://www.sitelocity.com/critical-path-css-generator

People use the technique of generating critical css, when they want to speed up the rendering of a page. Rather than loading a large external CSS file, they display the critical CSS in an inline style tag, then load the larger file after the page has rendered.

More info on this techinique can be found here:

https://www.tezify.com/how-to/defer_css_loading_with_loadcss/

**EDIT**

You mentioned how can we extract the classes from a HTML File.

If you take a very simple example webpage like this (contains approx 12 classes in html code):
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/sticky-footer/

And enter the URL into the generator page that I provided a link too. It will generate a block of CSS. Within that CSS you will find definitions for each of the 12 classes, together with some basic elements definitions etc.

Dean

Comment: thank you for your response but this seem to be working properly

Comment: can we do one thing that, extracting all classes from html file

Comment: Hi Player, are you saying that it works ok now?

You mention 'can we extract all classes'? That is what the css generator does for you. If extracts each class from the html and provides the css code for each class.